# ggplot2 geom_smooth() in R... loess, gam, splines, etc

Tags: r, ggplot2, spline, gam, loess

Hi I'm looking for some clarification here.

*Context*: I want to draw a line in a scatterplot that doesn't appear parametric, therefore I am using geom_smooth() in a ggplot. It automatically returns `geom_smooth: method="auto" and size of largest group is >=1000, so using gam with formula: y ~ s(x, bs = "cs"). Use 'method = x' to change the smoothing method.` I gather gam stands for generalized additive models and it has a cubic spline used.

Are the following perceptions correct?

-Loess estimates the response at specific values.

-Splines are approximations that connect different piecewise functions that fit the data (which make up the generalized additive model), and cubic splines are the specific type of spline used here.

Lastly, When should splines be used, when should loess be used?

Comment: Without data and code this is just a methods explanation and tutoring request. CrossValidated.com _might_ be more appropriate if you cannot edt this to meet SO's standards for "good (on-topic) questions".

Comment: thank you, i will ask the question there as it is more a methods explanation

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [the same question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189084/gam-vs-loess-vs-splines) has since been asked on CrossValidated, which is a more appropriate venue.

Comment: And he has no votes on it.